# How to unregister .on(drawend,....) event

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers

as shown in the below posted code, i have an event `#drawEvt` and it is registered for `drawend`. the problem i have is about unregistering the event. as shown below in the code
in method `deattachAll()` is how i unregister it, but it seems it does not work because the logs iinside the body of the `evtListenerOnDrawEnd` gets displayed several times.

one more imporatant note, is the algorithm is designed so that `digitize()` is being called after `deattachAll()`. in other words, initially `digitize()` is called and will never be called
again for a second time unless it is preceeded by a call to `deattachAll()`

please let me why the listener `#evtListenerOnDrawEnd` is invoked several times and how to fix it

**code**

```
#evtListenerOnDrawEnd = (evt, mapBuilderInstance, rasterLayer) => {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

getDrawGeomForSource(src, geomType) {
    return new Draw({
        source: src,
        type: geomType,
    });
}

his.#drawEvt = this.#mapBuilderInstance.getDrawGeomForSource(this.#vectorSource, 'Polygon');// to init this.`#drawEvt`

digitize() {
    this.#drawEvt.on('drawend', (evt) => this.#evtListenerOnDrawEnd(
        evt, this.#mapBuilderInstance, this.#rasterLayer
    ));
}

deattachAll() {
    this.#unregisterEvtListeners();
}

#unregisterEvtListeners() {
    this.#mapBuilderInstance.unregisterEvtListener('drawend', this.#drawEvt, this.#evtListenerOnDrawEnd);
}

unregisterEvtListener(eventName, type, callbackListener) {
    if (type) {
        type.un(eventName, callbackListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the callback is a named function you can use

```
handler = (evt) => { /* do something */ };
draw.on('drawend', handler);

draw.un('drawend', handler);
```

If it is an anonymous function you will need

```
key = draw.on('drawend', (evt) => { /* do something */ });

unByKey(key);
```

Comment: hi, i added a skelton how the #evtListenerOnDrawEnd looks like. would you please have a look and tell me which approach of the ansewer you posted i have to use?

Comment: i tried the second appoach you posted, the one with unbykey and it worked